# Anything wrong with this MySQL syntax?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

```
select 
    (`Setup` + `run` + `cleanup`) / `QNTY`
from 
    the_table 
where 
    date_field >= "2012-01-01" and
    Num = 4;
```

Every time I execute this query in MySQL workbench, the workbench application crashes immediately.  Looks like something that I have done many times before, not sure what the problem is.

Only thing I can think of is a problem with null values.  Sometimes (`Setup` + `run` + `cleanup`) will return a null, and sometimes `QNTY` is null also.

I just checked, and this query also causes a crash:

```
select 
    (`Setup` + `run` + `cleanup`) / `QNTY`
from 
    the_table
where 
    date_field >= "2012-01-01" and
    (`Setup` + `run` + `cleanup`) is not null and
    `QNTY` is not null and
    `QNTY` != 0 and
    Num = 4
```

Thanks.

Comment: yeah i just checked, it still crashes

Comment: I quickly tested this via a PHP MyAdmin interface. The math worked fine. I tried a null in the addition part and a null in the division part and the result was just null. Maybe it is a Workbench bug?

Comment: Maybe you should check this out; http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

Comment: start the workbench from terminal and see the logs when it crashes. it may give some hints.

Comment: If QNTY is very, very small, the result would be very, very large. What the smallest value for QNTY? btw, if QNTY is an int, forget this as a reason

Comment: what are the datatypes of all the columns involved? i've seen problems treating blobs etc as numeric.

Answer (score 1):

I would try

```
select 
    (coalesce(Setup, 0) + coalesce(run, 0) + coalesce(cleanup, 0)) / QNTY
from 
    the_table
where 
    date_field >= '2012-01-01' and
    Num = 4 and
    coalesce(QNTY, 0) <>0
```

Comment: Still crashed using this syntax, it must be a bug in Workbench

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in workbench as suggested by Darkwater23 in the comments.  I tried on the old MySQL Query Browser and it executed fine with nulls and zeros and everything.